# Android Studio - ListView refreshes only after other code has been run

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a notifyDataSetChanged(); executing after the deletion of each item in an ArrayList. The code runs just fine, it's just that the ListView doesn't get updated until the other code is finished. How do I make the ListView code update as the program is executed instead of at the end?

```
    public static void remove(Corp corp){
    int toRemove = MainActivity.loadedLevel.indexOf(corp);
    MainActivity.loadedLevel.remove(toRemove);
    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This block currently runs about 3 times in my code, but the ListView isn't updated until the rest of the code in the whole program has been executed.

Comment: If you are runing this code on main thread it is obvious and normal behaviour ... let me explain: there a few small dwarfs which are drawing UI ... 60 times per second ... we call them main/ui thread ... they can also do other stuff like execute your code ... but they can only do one thing at a time ... so obviously when dwarfs are working with your code they can draw UI

Comment: solution is to hire another bunch of dwarves ... second team should send a pigeon to the UI team sometimes to force em to redraw UI ... remeber they do not share any tools(CalledFromWrongThreadException)

Comment: Duh, but i'm executing the commands one at a time. its just that for some reason, if I were to do: out.print("Hi");notifyDataSetChanged();out.print("hey"); it would print out "HiHey" before even touching ListView. How do I fix this?